# Is there a way to block terminal size? Or does exist a terminal which allows this?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, python-curses

I'm writing a program in python curses, I just wanted to prevent curses crashing with terminal resizing so I was wondering if there is a way to lock terminal size to 80x24.

Comment: Even if there was a way (I doubt it is, but don't know), you can't enforce this - I use whatever terminal I want to run your program. So the correct cause of action is to deal with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161552/python-curses-handling-window-terminal-resize

Comment: I could create a launcher which launches the program in the terminal i want.

Comment: Is it curses that is crashing, or your code?

Comment: What happens is that if i have a long string and i make the terminal smaller the string curses returns error: 
`error: addstr() returned ERR`

Comment: @AlessioRagno I don't have that terminal you want installed, so your launcher crashes - square one. Honestly: if you force me to use 80x25 terminal windows on my 27" screen, I'm annoyed. If you force me to use a 140x80 terminal window on my netbook, I'm also annoyed. Accept reality - we live in a day and age of resizable terminals. Since roundabout the 90ies....

Comment: @AlessioRagno the documentation of curses is somewhat lacking, but some experimentation shows that addstr will in fact fail if the str exceeds the limits of the surface you draw to. But in the end this is to be expected, you need to adapt your rendering to a smaller size (or display an error-message at least that says "sorry, can't run in small terminals")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Terminal resize python curses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571686/prevent-terminal-resize-python-curses)

Comment: It is certainly a duplicate, and OP is unlikely to get a better answer.

Comment: The program is for a chain of laundries so they dont have to care about the size, and if they want to make the term bigger they could press Ctrl +.

Comment: It is not a copy, in the other question i wanted to address to programmers who use curses, here I am talking about terminal.